# Formulating diagonal constraint for N Queen problem C++

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm having a problem with the N Queens problem. I try to implement a constraint that the queens cannot be placed in the diagonals. The program is embedded in CPLEX.

Here is what I have for the column constraint, that max. one queen is placed per column:

```
    for (rr = 0; rr < ROWS; rr++)
{
    IloExpr constraint2(env);
    for (rr=0;rr<ROWS;rr++)
        constraint2 += x[rr][cc];
    mod.add(constraint2 == 1);
    constraint2.end();
}
```

I tried to implement this for the upper left diagonal:

```
    for (d = rr - 1; d < (ROWS - 2); d++)
{
    IloExpr constraint3(env);
    for (d = cc - 1; d < (ROWS - 2); d++)
        constraint3 += x[d][d];
    mod.add(constraint3 >= 1);
    constraint3.end();
}
```

But this does not work. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and provide [mcve].

Comment: IMHO, you are using the wrong algorithm.  You should be checking relative to the current location, not checking the entire board.  If you consider the board a grid (Cartesian Coordinates), you should be able to use some geometry and algebra to detect if there is a queen on a *line*.

Comment: I used this diagonal trick in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65653648/10553341

Comment: Consider which element if `x` is accessed when `rr == 0` in your second code block.

Answer (score 0):

Within CPLEX you can rely on MIP.

With OPL you could write

```
int Dim=400;
range Bord=1..Dim;

dvar boolean x[Bord][Bord];

subject to
{
  forall(i in Bord) sum(j in Bord) x[i][j]==1;
  forall(i in Bord) sum(j in Bord) x[j][i]==1;
  forall(k in 2..2*Dim) sum(i,j in Bord:i+j==k) x[i][j]<=1;
  forall(k in 1-Dim..Dim-1) sum(i,j in Bord:i-j==k) x[i][j]<=1;
  
}
```

But with Dim=400 it takes 15 s on my laptop whereas with CPOptimizer within CPLEX , in less than 1 s

```
using CP;
int Dim=400;
range Bord=1..Dim;
dvar int queen[Bord] in Bord;
dvar int d1[Bord];
dvar int d2[Bord];

constraints {
forall(ind in Bord) {
d1[ind]== queen[ind]+ind;
d2[ind ]== queen[ind]-ind;
};

allDifferent(queen); // One queen max per line
allDifferent(d1);    // One queen max per diagonal 1
allDifferent(d2);  // One queen max per diagonal 2
};
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thank you for your help. I must be honest that my programming skills are limited and I'm just getting started to program MIP's in CPLEX and the framework for Constraint 2 is a start point for my project. Could you help me to bring these formulations for the diagonals into the given framework?

Comment: If your programming skills are limited, I think you should use a modeling language like OPL rather than C++. See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimization-aka-prescriptive-analytics-should-we-write-fleischer/ . Now if you want to stick to C++ you could try to change mod.add(constraint3 >= 1); into mod.add(constraint3 <= 1); since you want maximum 1 queen per diagonal and not minimum 1