# How to use backtracking in bfs: N-Queens Problem

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, backtracking

The problem description is as follows: The n-queens puzzle is the problem of placing n queens on an n x n chessboard such that no two queens attack each other.

Given an integer n, return all distinct solutions to the n-queens puzzle. You may return the answer in any order.

So no two queens can be on the same column, row or diagonals.

Example input/output
Input: n = 4
Output: [[".Q..","...Q","Q...","..Q."],["..Q.","Q...","...Q",".Q.."]]
"." represents an empty cell on an n*n board, and "Q" represents a queen.

So far the solution that I came up with is through simple bfs as I noticed that every two queens are a knight move from each other. And since every column needs a queen, I iterate through the first row and check for possible solution starting at row 0 and the ith column. The problem is that I will only have one solution for each column, but there may be two. I think the problem involves backtracking. But I don't know how or if it is possible to include backtracking in the bfs.

```
def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
        moves = ((1, 2), (1, -2), (-1, 2), (-1, -2), (2, 1), (2, -1), (-2, 1), (-2, -1))
        
        queue = deque()
        
        res = []
        ans = []
        for i in range(n):
            queue.append((0, i, [(0, i)]))
            diagonalR = set([0-i])
            diagonalL = set([0+i])
            visitedCol = set([i])
            visitedRow = set([0])
            while queue:
                cr, cc, queens = queue.popleft()
                for di, dj in moves:
                    if len(queens) == n and queens not in ans:
                        ans.append(queens)
                        res.append(['.' * x[1] + 'Q' + '.' * (n-1-x[1]) for x in queens])
                        continue
                    if 0 <= cr + di < n and 0 <= cc + dj < n and cr + di not in visitedRow and cc + dj not in visitedCol and (cr + di) + (cc + dj) not in diagonalL and (cr + di) - (cc + dj) not in diagonalR:
                        queens.append((cr + di, cc + dj))
                        queue.append((cr + di, cc + dj, queens))
                        visitedCol.add(cc + dj)
                        visitedRow.add(cr + di)
                        diagonalR.add((cr + di) - (cc + dj))
                        diagonalL.add((cr + di) + (cc + dj))
                        
        return res
```

For example, for n = 5, there are 10 ways for arranging 5-queens but I only got 5.

```
My output: [["Q....","..Q..","....Q",".Q...","...Q."],[".Q...","...Q.","Q....","..Q..","....Q"],
["..Q..","....Q",".Q...","...Q.","Q...."],["...Q.",".Q...","....Q","..Q..","Q...."],
["....Q","..Q..","Q....","...Q.",".Q..."]]
```

```
Expected output: [["Q....","..Q..","....Q",".Q...","...Q."],
["Q....","...Q.",".Q...","....Q","..Q.."],[".Q...","...Q.","Q....","..Q..","....Q"],
[".Q...","....Q","..Q..","Q....","...Q."],["..Q..","Q....","...Q.",".Q...","....Q"],
["..Q..","....Q",".Q...","...Q.","Q...."],["...Q.","Q....","..Q..","....Q",".Q..."],
["...Q.",".Q...","....Q","..Q..","Q...."],["....Q",".Q...","...Q.","Q....","..Q.."],
["....Q","..Q..","Q....","...Q.",".Q..."]]
```

Comment: Since you're required to return all solutions, it is probably not worthwhile to rack you brain over BDF vs backtracking.  You can find a backtracking solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65677716/5237560)

Comment: On larger boards there are solutions where some queens have to be placed elsewhere then a knight-jump away from a previously placed queen. See [here](https://oeis.org/A002562/a002562_1.pdf). You are not implementing BFS either, because you mutate the same state that you already put in the queue, and leave some state aspects out of the queue (all the visited info). So this cannot work. It would need too much updating, and then still the approach with knight jumps is not correct.